# CentOS 6.4 X86_64 Uses too much RAM and SWAP

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, centos

I`ve been surfing the web for about 1 week and everything I've found is: "CentOS knows how to use the ram, don't worry" but I really think this is a problem.
I have a VM with a recent/clean installation of CentOS 6.4 X86_64 final with 1.5GB RAM, 1 processor / 4 cores and 700MB SWAP and the problem is the memory consumption.
I installed postgresql, pgadmin3, JRE 7.25 (NOT JDK nor OpenJDK), netbeans 7.3.1 and apache but most of the time (99%) I only need NB and firefox open at the same time and obviously the httpd and pgsql services.
Well, when I open netbeans it uses 300Mb - 350MB, and Firefox 100MB - 150MB and the initial memory used by the system is about 250MB, so there are 750MB and the system monitor and **free -m** command confirm that, but within a few minutes the system eats all my free memory and starts using 100MB - 200MB SWAP And it gets really SssLOOOWWW..
I am developping a simple PHP / JS / HTML website.
When the system eats all my memory and swap, the **free -m** command returns this:

```
    free -m
       total    used      free   shared    buffers    cached
Mem: 1511532  1477256    34276      0       18652     89325
-/+ b../c..:  1369279   142253
Swap: 711320   198652   512668
```

I know the actual free memory is about 140MB but:

- That is a lot of memory used and the system gets really slow
- If I close NB and FF I only get half of the memory used by both released (250MB)
- The SWAP is never released (only on reboot)
- if I open FF and NB again it consumes the 250MB again and EVEN MORE
  SWAP!!!

I`ve tried this:

- I changed the Swappiness value from 60 to 5 and actually the system
  doesn`t use the swap until it gets the 95% of the RAM used.
- I disabled the unnecesary programs at startup like bluetooth mgr, mail, login sound, energy mngr (it is a desktop pc).
- I set the JVM Max heap size to 256MB and actually between the java/netbeans (Virtual + shared) = actual memory used is never > 400MB
- If I check service by service (including the multiple httpd and PGSql subservices) the memory used is not more than 750MB
- I have to say that when I test the exact same website in Win 7/WAMP the memory used by Netbeans, PGAdmin3, Firefox and posgres services is almost the same as it is in centOS (500MB) and with the initial memory used by the system (900MB) the total used memory is 1400MB and it doesn`t change so is is not a programming error.
- Finally, I have reinstalled CentOS and the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I reinstalled CentOS x64 and the problem with the memory ussage persists so I have a theory for my own specific case and from my own experience.
If you are not totally sure that your programs/applications are designed for 64 bits you better install 32 bit CentOS EVEN FOR AMD X64.
**My case:**

> - Amd Athlon X4 640 Processor (64bit)
> - VMware 7
> - 1 processor / 4 cores, 1.5GB RAM
> - CentOS 6.4 32bit
> - apache (httpd)
> - Php 5.3.3
> - Postgresql, (server, client, contrib, libpq)
> - pgAdmin III
> - Firefox 17 ESR (default centos browser) with **firebug and colorzilla** extensions
> - Opera (Last release)
> - JRE 7.25 (Only for netbeans to work -- Downloaded from Oracle not openJDK)
> - Netbeans 7.3.1 (PHP - HTML5)

Now I have opened pgadmin, netbeans (with 10 active tabs) and firefox and the free memory is (150+MB free + 20+MB buffers + 200+MB cached) and if I need more memory when I open opera or any other program some of the cached memory is released AS IT SHOULD BE DONE.
oh, and the SWAP use is 0.00000000 that as you know it can be really helpful but if you are using a program loaded in the swap (totally or partially) it is at least 10 times slower than a program loaded in the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your memory using "htop" you would see that the memory bar has 3 colors. I would guess that most of the memory used is yellow in your case.

Basically your memory is being used by various OS caches. These caches are pushed out of the memory as your system needs. The system holds on to the ram copy so that centos can execute faster if same commands/programs are executed again while the data is still in memory cache. This explains why you are only part of the memory used is release once the app is closed.

This has never been a cause of slow down for me.

I have experienced firefox memory usage balloon on as you keep using.

Perhaps it is a virtualization platfrom issue. What is your host os and what virtualization platfrom are you using?